# ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Generated with JDK 11

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, persistence

I created a JavaFX Ant project in Apache Netbeans 12.0 with the JDK 11 from bellsoft. Then i created a database connection with an sqlite database, which is a file on my pc. In this database are two tables.

I clicked right on the project and selected "New->Entity Classes from Database...", then i created the two classes from the tables. Now i want to clean and build the project, but i get this error.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Is it because of the jdk?

```
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.MetadataMirrorFactory.setEnvironments(MetadataMirrorFactory.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:368)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:896)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1222)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1334)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:936)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:311)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:57)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1404)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1133)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.forEach(Vector.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:391)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Generated
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 88 more
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9zor.png
```

Comment: In Java 11, several Java EE dependencies have been removed from the SE (that were originally related to the EE environment) and `javax.annotation.*` is part of that. Thats the reason for your problem. From Java 11 onwards, you have to add `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api` as a dependency manually.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Add below dependency and try to run :**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where can i put dependencies? I created the project: "Java with Ant". Do i need Maven for this?

Comment: You can add maven dependencies to Apache Ant by using Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks. This link should help : http://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/

Comment: I don't think it makes sense as a new java programmer to jump into Maven Artifact Resolver here. Either [A] choose to stick with ant, and download this dependency separately (search for it on search.maven.org and follow the downloads link. gets you here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/ - pick the plain jar), and add it to your classpath, or [B] ditch ant, switch to maven or gradle.

Comment: I never used build tools before, so i used the first solution, thank you..
But i think, i should get into building tools and how to handle them.

Comment: You always can download jar and put it into your 'lib' dir.

Comment: Anyone who is trying to resolve similar issue and still faces the issue after importing above dependency, please try to check which version of JDK is selected for project in IDE

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ, try to check the following:
Setting  -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Java Compiler -> Per-module bytecode version.

I set it as 1.8 and my JDK was 11. Because of this conflict, all the attempts were failed.

[image]